# How to find out the exact number of followers on YouTube?

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to find out the exact number of subscribers on the channel via API.

The channel is not on my account, but I have the rights to watch.
I need the exact amount shown on `studio.youtube.com`.

I use:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics,snippet&mine=true&access_token=[your_access_token]`.

But it shows only a personal account, and if you replace `mine` with `managedByMe`, I will see an error:

[image: Img error]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take your time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Afterwards, edit your post, adding to it relevant missing information (without which the other SO users cannot come to your help). For example, do obey to SO guidelines: [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8327971), but ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) plain text.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [official YouTube Data API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/), the only way to obtain the subscriber count of a given channel is through the following properties:

> [**statistics.subscriberCount**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.subscriberCount) (unsigned long)
> The number of subscribers that the channel has. This value is rounded down to three significant figures. Please see the [Revision History](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_09_10_2019) or the [YouTube Help Center](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6051134) for more details about how subscriber counts are rounded.
>
> [**statistics.hiddenSubscriberCount**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#statistics.hiddenSubscriberCount) (boolean)
> Indicates whether the channel's subscriber count is publicly visible.

The number provided is rounded -- thus is not exact. Consequently, however unfortunate, is true that you cannot obtain the info you're looking for from the YouTube Data API.

---

According to [this support post](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/6543166?hl=en) (the emphasis below is mine):

> To create more consistency everywhere that we publicly display subscriber counts, starting in August 2019, we’ll begin showing the abbreviated subscriber number across all public YouTube surfaces. Third parties that use YouTube’s API Services will also access the same public facing counts you see on YouTube. *Creators will still be able to see their exact number of subscribers in YouTube Studio*.

> The change will take place across YouTube and the public YouTube Data API Service. *Creators will continue to see their full subscriber counts privately in YouTube Studio and YouTube Analytics*.

Indeed exact numbers are shown only to creators within YouTube Studio or YouTube Analytics only.

Comment: So they make us create service accounts, api keys, aouth endpoints (and low freaking quotas).. just to get less data than if I had just used a scraper? I am a bit confused i need to know my channels exact subscriber count.. why.. cant.. I .. see ..it 