# YouTube Data API v3 is not getting the correct subscribers count

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using *the YouTube Data API v3* for my work, but it does not get the right subscribers count when I ask for that.

In my code I use this URL:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=" + MY_USERNAME + "&key=" + MY_KEY`

and I get this JSON back:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "jEJnVwl_Vgc3tM1asn0kb2Mu7as",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "CcPFuF-ke8OIYEvfXXCaktL89BA",
      "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "26294085594",
        "commentCount": "0",
        "subscriberCount": "107000000",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "4223"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is good for me is `subscriberCount` in the `items`. This JSON result is a test I did for PewDiePie's channel, but I expect the number change every time I refresh due to his fame; and if you look carefully you know it is not even the right number.

Is there a way to get the full number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the exact number of followers on youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536872/how-to-find-out-the-exact-number-of-followers-on-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

A while back Google changed how it's APIs worked on YouTube to prevent drama.

In other words, all subscriber counts are rounded to prevent "sub battles", live count streams and websites that would show the decline of a creator. Sorry about this!

Comment: that is sad :(,  so there is not any other way to get it?

Comment: Sorry, but there is not.