# API gives constant subscriber count

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to make a web app which shows real time subscribercount of a youtube channel.But it just shows me a constant number.The number of subscribers are not updated in next call of API.
I have written this function to get subs.I have tried with ID as well still no updates.Help me out.

Javascript

```
function getsubscribers(username, element) {
      let url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=${KEY}&forUsername=${username}&    part=statistics`;

      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          element.innerText = data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
        });
    }
```

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [How to find out the exact number of followers on YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537230/8327971). That answer is negative: you cannot get real subscriber count through the API, only rounded counts.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube analytics has the same issue.

This is because the YouTube API is not a realtime api, the data seams to be updated once a day.