# Get exact youtuber subscriber count with youtube api python

Tags: python, youtube-api

I have a python script that does give me a subscriber count but it is rounded to the nearest million is there any way o get exact real time sub count?

```
import urllib.request
import json

name = "PewDiePie"
key = "SECRET"

while True:
    data = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
    part=statistics&forUsername="+name+"&key="+key).read()
    subs = json.loads(data)["items"][0]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"]
    print(subs)
```

Comment: any reason you are not using the google api python client library?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: [How to find out the exact number of followers on YouTube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536872/how-to-find-out-the-exact-number-of-followers-on-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

When Accessing the YouTube data api using an API key the API returns limited information in some cases.  For Example

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=PewDiePie&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Rounds off the users subscriber count.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "WYKQJMLX47xl94l7e-SdlKeFpqA",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "aqYfRJecxFtoy7NM2m8F_19qq7s",
      "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "27492358931",
        "subscriberCount": "110000000",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "4360"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now if you were authorized as the owner of this channel you may get the correct count.  However API keys only give you access to public data, IMO the exact number may possibly be consider private data and only delivered to the owner of the account.   No real way to test this theory unless you can contact them.

Comment: There's no way to get the accurate subscriber count with the official API. Even if you're authorized as a channel owner you will still only get the rounded number. Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#release_notes_09_10_2019

Comment: This api is very limited