# YouTube Data Api V3 Get Live Subscriber Count for Multiple channels with jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I have been getting youtube channel subscriber count with Youtube Data Api V3 for one channel. Right now I would like to get the live subscriber count of 50 YouTube channels.

Does Youtube allow sending a request with multiple channel ids? Or is there any approach that should be used to give live subscriber count for multiple channels with jQuery?

Example of what I'm looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftMnmPC82qM&ab_channel=MDM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your YouTube Data API v3 key then use [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint this way: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCq-Fj5jknLsUf-MWSy4_brA,UCbCmjCuTUZos6Inko4u57UQ&key=YOUR_API_KEY then in the answer the field `subscriberCount` is what you are looking for.

You can add up to 50 YouTube channels ids in the `id` parameter.
Furthermore as pointed out by [stvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327971/stvar) the `subscriberCounter` is an approximation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537230

Comment: I realized this url does not give live subscriber counts. Do you have an idea of which url should be used to featch live subscriber counts?

Comment: I stated that it was an approximation. It seems that YouTube doesn't want to receive a lot of requests just to let people know live subscriber counts. As Social Blade and many other websites are doing the same approximation and there isn't any webpage even on YouTube default spectator UI showing the precise subscriber count, there doesn't seem to be any way to get a precise one. Some websites showing a "precise count" have in their source code variables the word "estimation"