# How to get the exact subscribers of own youtube channel throughout API

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

i'm trying to retrieve the number of subscribers, but the number that I received was rounded, not correct number.
By seeing the API docs, it is impossible to get exact subscribers number throughout youtube data API. So, I came up with the idea that using Analytics API, However there is no way to fetch the number of subscribers. Is there any way to do this?? thanks.
(It is possible to see the subscribers number by opening youtube but I can't do this throughout API)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537230/12511801) - quote: ***Reminder**: The change will take place across YouTube and the public YouTube Data API Service. Creators will continue to see their full subscriber counts privately in YouTube Studio and YouTube Analytics.*.

Answer (score 0):

These are the only metrics that the analytics api provides:

- annotationClickThroughRate
- annotationCloseRate
- verageViewDuration
- comments
- dislikes
- estimatedMinutesWatched
- estimatedRevenue
- likes
- shares
- subscribersGained
- subscribersLost
- viewerPercentage
- views

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics

Also See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537230/12772716

Comment: Thanks for replying!!! Ok, at this moment it is difficult to get exact subscriber without any caluculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current subscribers via the YouTube Data API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels
under statistics.subscriberCount

Additionally you could calculate the historical subscribercount by combining YouTube Data and Analytics API:
subscriberCount - (SUM(subscribersGained) - SUM(subscribersLost))

Comment: Thanks for replying and apriciate it for giving me great info. Now I realized that to get correct number, I have to combine information getting by youtube analytics API and Data API I'm going to try it !! thanks again.

Comment: subscriberCount is round down by 3 significant figures. So once you get above 1K you can't get accurate subcount anymore. For example 1.000 to 1.009 will all show as 1.000. I'm trying to find a different way to be able to get the stats accurate above 1k subs.